# Assigning range to an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have some mini problem. How can I assign a range into an array, like this one:

**input file**: `clktest.spf`

```
*
.GLOBAL  vcc! vss!
*
.SUBCKT  eclk_l_25h brg2eclk<1> brg2eclk<0> brg_cs_sel brg_out brg_stop cdivx<1>
+ eclkout1<24> eclkout1<23> eclkout1<22> eclkout1<21> eclkout1<20> eclkout1<19>
+ mc1_brg_dyn mc1_brg_outen mc1_brg_stop mc1_div2<1> mc1_div2<0> mc1_div3p5<1>
+ mc1_div3p5<0> mc1_div_mux<3> mc1_div_mux<2> mc1_div_mux<1> mc1_div_mux<0>
+ mc1_gsrn_dis<0> pclkt6_0 pclkt6_1 pclkt7_0 pclkt7_1 slip<1> slip<0>
+ ulc_pclkgpll0<1> ulc_pclkgpll0<0> ulq_eclkcib<1> ulq_eclkcib<0>
*
*Net Section
*
*|GROUND_NET 0
*
*|NET eclkout3<48> 2.79056e-16
*|P (eclkout3<48> X 0 54.8100 -985.6950)
*|I (RXR0<16>#NEG RXR0<16> NEG X 0 54.2255 -985.6950)
C1 RXR0<16>#NEG 0 5.03477e-17
C2 eclkout3<48> 0 2.28708e-16
Rk_6_1 eclkout3<48> RXR0<16>#NEG 0.110947
```

**output** (this should be the saved value in the array)

```
.SUBCKT  eclk_l_25h brg2eclk<1> brg2eclk<0> brg_cs_sel brg_out brg_stop cdivx<1>
+ eclkout1<24> eclkout1<23> eclkout1<22> eclkout1<21> eclkout1<20> eclkout1<19>
+ mc1_brg_dyn mc1_brg_outen mc1_brg_stop mc1_div2<1> mc1_div2<0> mc1_div3p5<1>
+ mc1_div3p5<0> mc1_div_mux<3> mc1_div_mux<2> mc1_div_mux<1> mc1_div_mux<0>
+ mc1_gsrn_dis<0> pclkt6_0 pclkt6_1 pclkt7_0 pclkt7_1 slip<1> slip<0>
+ ulc_pclkgpll0<1> ulc_pclkgpll0<0> ulq_eclkcib<1> ulq_eclkcib<0>
*
*Net Section
```

**my simple code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = "clktest.spf";

open INFILE, $input or die "Can't open $input" ;

my @allports;
while (<INFILE>){
    @allports = /\.SUBCKT/ ... /\*Net Section/ ;
    print @allports;
}
```

I am doing a correct job of assigning the selected range into an array? If not how can I modify this code?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop only gives you one line at a time so you can't assign all of the lines you want at once. Use `push` instead to grow the array line by line.

Also, you should be using *lexical* file handles like `$in_fh` (rather than global ones like `INFILE`) with the three-parameter form of `open`, and you should include the `$!` variable in the `die` string so that you know *why* the open failed.

This is how your program should look

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'clktest.spf';

open my $in_fh, '<', $input or die "Can't open $input: $!" ;

my @allports;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    push @allports, $_ if /\.SUBCKT/ ... /\*Net Section/;
}

print @allports;
```

Note that, if all you want to do is to print the selected lines from the file, you can forget about the array and replace `push @allports, $_` with `print`

Answer (score 0):

The `<INFILE>` inside a `while` will read the file line-by-line, so not a right place to apply a regex which need to cover more than one line. In order to get a substring, the simplest way is to first join all these lines. And only after that you apply your regex.

```
my $contents = "";
while ( <INFILE> ) {
    $contents = $contents . $_;
}
$contents =~ s/.*(\.SUBCKT.*\*Net Section).*/$1/s; # remove unneeded part
```

Please note that there is `/s` modifier in the last part of substitution line. This is required because `$contents` contains newlines.

To get the substring into array, just use split `my @allports = split("\n", $contents);`

Comment: What does `.*/$1` means on your regex? And on your split code, is it really `¥n`?

Comment: The `.*` before `(` and after `)` means unneeded part. `$1` will contains the string between these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the follow-up, Once I had found the section of the file, i will do something like this:

        $contents =~ tr/\+,\.,\*//d;
        $contents =~ s/SUBCKT  //; 
        $contents =~ s/Net Section//;
        @ports = split (' ', $contents);

Can I do something smaller than this?